# jQuery slideDown, hide with browser problem

Tags: jquery, slidedown

```
$("#list").slideDown("slow"); //code to slide down the div dag when it is clicked.
```

It is working fine but when I clicked on the tag, the browser is suddenly scrolling up to the top.

So I have to scroll down to the tag to see its contents.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your click handler, you need to `return false` or use `event.preventDefault();`. An example click handler would be:

```
$("#element").click(function(event){

  $("#list").slideDown("slow");

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your HTML code it's impossible to be certain, but this behaviour is usually seen when you have something like `<a href='#' onclick='.....'>`. The `#` tells the browser to go to the top of the page.